# Static Hash Table

Tags: database, oracle, rdbms

**Question**

Now suppose that the Sites table is stored in a static hash table with SiteID as the hash key. Load the following records with SiteID values 9, 16, 12, 7, 20, 30 into the table. Assume that the file uses eight buckets numbered 0 to 7 and records are inserted into the hash table in the given order using the hash function h(K) = K mod 8, where K is a SiteID value. Each bucket is one disk block and holds 2 records. Show all your workings.

**Solution to this question**

```
h(9) = 9 mod 8 = 1 
h(16) = 16 mod 8 = 0 
h(12) = 12 mod 8 = 4 
h(7) = 7 mod 8 = 7 
h(20) = 20 mod 8 = 4 
h(30) = 30 mod 8 = 6
```

**My question**

How do you get a very last value of each row? can anyone please explain me

Comment: Its not my bloody homework!!!!!! Im studying for my exam and i just dont undestand how do u determine which 2hicj number goes to whitch bucket! If u dont have a clue what is the answer please dont comment and dont waste my time

Comment: APC you should use an answer by user CForPhone as an example how to answer people's questions. Hope this hint will help

Comment: Alternatively first Google result for `Oracle + Mod` [points to this page of documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions088.htm)

Comment: If you cut'n'paste text from a clearly academic source you should not surprised if people get the wrong impression.  So please take this as a hint to ask a better question next time ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder whether I understood your question correctly... but here is my answer and I hope it helps.

Modulo operation (mod, or the "%" operator in C/C++/Java), "finds the remainder after division of one number by another (sometimes called modulus).".

If the source of confusion is this operation, you can read [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation)

Comment: Thank you sir, it makes sense now!!! Spend hell lot of time trying to figure it out. As soon as you mentioned remainder and division i got it!